# PayPal - Class not found, what did I miss?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am working on a WordPress plugin and I am trying to integrate PayPal.

I have included the PayPal SDK within my project which is right below paypal_init.php (the file below).

Here is my code, however I am getting the error

> Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\plugins\wp-content\plugins\membership\paypal\paypal_init.php on line 13

What am I doing wrong, and why can I not use these classes - I'm stumped?

```
<?php

// Require the PHP SDK.
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php' );

use Paypal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

$paypal = new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        $clientid, // Client ID
        $secret  // Secret
    )
);


?>
```

Comment: Can you check in your error log whether the require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php' ); loaded up properly? This looks like PHP does not have the lass library available... In otherwords, make sure you have the correct path to PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that the classes were not working, because I did not use composer with the SDK. Apparently you HAVE to use composer, so that the classes are called properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `use` statements mean that you don't need the full class namespaces:

```
$paypal = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        $clientid, // Client ID
        $secret  // Secret
    )
);
```